# Unit test a class which uses httpclient

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to write the unit test case for this class which uses the `HttpURLConnection`. I have not used any mocking framework till now hence getting hard time finalizing the approach.

```
public class DemoRestClient implements Closeable {

    private final String instanceId;
    private final String requestId;
    private HttpURLConnection conn;

    public DemoRestClient(String instance, String reqId, String url) {
        this.instanceId = instance;
        this.requestId = reqId;

        try {
            URL urlRequest = new URL(url);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlRequest.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to connect", iox);
        }
    }

    public InputStream run() {

        try {
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            return new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Data fetching failed!", iox);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Please shade some light if you have gone through this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either provide the `HttpURLConnection` at contruction time or let `DemoRestClient` delegate to a factory (or similar) to create the `HttpURLConnection`.

For example:

```
public DemoRestClient(String instance, String reqId, HttpURLConnection connection) {
    ...
    this.conn = connection;
}
```

Or

```
public DemoRestClient(String instance, String reqId, ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    ...
    this.conn = connectionFactory.create();
}
```

With either of these approaches you will control the actual `HttpURLConnection` instance in use within `DemoRestService` and then you can start to mock it in support of your desired test behaviour.

For example:

```
@Test
public void someTest() throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = Mockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
    String instance = "...";
    String reqId = "...";

    DemoRestClient demoRestClient = new DemoRestClient(instance, reqId, connection);

    // in case you need to mock a response from the conneciton
    Mockito.when(connection.getInputStream()).thenReturn(...);

    demoRestClient.run();

    // in case you want to verify invocations on the connection
    Mockito.verify(connection).setRequestMethod("GET");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the creation of the `HttpURLConnection` object out of the `DemoRestClient` class and inject a constructed instance through a constructor.

This will allow you to create a mock of `HttpURLConnection` type that you could use in your unit tests to verify that the `DemoRestClient` interacts with the `HttpURLConnection` mock in the way you expect it to.